# What does the '-I.' option cause in a g++ call?

Tags: gcc, g++, makefile, gnu-make

In a makefile the compiler variables `CXXFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` are each set like this:

```
CXXFLAGS = -I. $(shell something)
```

Whereas the `-I directory` option is used to include another standard lib directory to the buildprocess,  I cannot figure out what effect the '.' has in the upper example. The `makefile` works even after removing the `'-I.'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` references the current directory (whether that's on Windows or Unix-type systems).

`-I.` just adds the current directory to the *include file* search path. `-L.` would include that to the *library* search path.